API client keeps waiting for response until timeout when server side has already responded
I am testing my API server side code in Java Spring Boot. The server side has already responded but the client side keeps waiting for the response body until the client side timeout, server side timeout or load balancer timeout. What might be the problem?
...
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
    @PostMapping("/hello-world")
    public ResponseEntity helloworld() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        String respBody = "hello, world";
        /* do some logics */
        return new ResponseEntity<>(respBody, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}


For some reason the Content-Length is response header was altered in the "do some logics" block and has a value more than 12 (the length of the response body hello, world), say, 15.
The API client, therefore, keeps waiting for the extra 3 (15-12) that will never arrive.
To solve this, I set the Content-Length correct before returning the response.
...
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
    @PostMapping("/hello-world")
    public ResponseEntity helloworld() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        String respBody = "hello, world";
        /* do some logics */
        headers.setContentLength(respBody.length());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(respBody, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

